# Redis hasKey method return NULL

Tags: spring, spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis

When can redis hasKey method return null? I have seen that if we pass null also in method param it returns false .So is there any scenario when that method can return null?

Answer (score 0):

If you use `spring data redis`,It mainly includes the following situations

1. Key does not exist；
2. After pipline；
3. After transaction execution

you can take a look at the underlying implementation `org. Springframework. Data. Redis. Connection. Jedis. Jediskeycommands #exists (byte []...)`. Detail as following:

```java
    @Override
    public Boolean hasKey(K key) {
        byte[] rawKey = rawKey(key);
        return execute(connection -> connection.exists(rawKey), true);
    }
```

```java
   @Nullable
    @Override
    public Long exists(byte[]... keys) {

        Assert.notNull(keys, "Keys must not be null!");
        Assert.noNullElements(keys, "Keys must not contain null elements!");

        try {
            if (**isPipelined**()) {
                pipeline(connection.newJedisResult(connection.getRequiredPipeline().exists(keys)));
                return **null**;
            }
            if (**isQueueing**()) {
                transaction(connection.newJedisResult(connection.getRequiredTransaction().exists(keys)));
                return **null**;
            }
            return connection.getJedis().exists(keys);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw connection.convertJedisAccessException(ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain the 3 things you mentioned because i tested from junit if i was passing null to the haskey method then also false was returned.

Comment: In fact, your question is in line with scenario 1,Your key `null` may no longer exist in redis

Answer (score 0):

`RedisTemplate.hasKey` calls `RedisKeyCommands.exists` with the key you provide (which must not be `null`, btw).

From [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/redis/connection/RedisKeyCommands.html#exists(byte%5B%5D)), `exists` returns:

> true if key exists. null when used in pipeline / transaction.

So as long as you're not using [pipelining](https://redis.io/docs/manual/pipelining/) or [transactions](https://redis.io/docs/manual/transactions/), `hasKey` won't return `null`.